# Create List from Data matching Criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, list

I have a table consisting of 2 Columns. Column A holds List of Customer Names, and Column B hold Projects Names.

I need to create List (for Data Validation Use) which holds all projects related to Specific Customer Name.

Customer name is manually entered by user, where according to the entered customer name, the list should be updated to the corresponding projects.

How to create such list?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Make the DV List thru concatenation and store it as a global string variable.  Once it has been created, it can be used as DV criteria.

To make the List:

```
Dim DVList As String

Sub MakeDVList()
    Dim N As Long, I As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
    N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For I = 2 To N
        If .Cells(I, "A").Value = "jim" Then
            DVList = DVList & "," & .Cells(I, "B").Value
        End If
    Next I
    DVList = Mid(DVList, 2)
    End With
End Sub
```

This assumes that the name/project data starts in row #2

Once this has been run, select a cell and run:

```
Sub SetDV()
    With ActiveCell.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=DVList
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Ideally, both subs and the global should be in the same module.

Comment: Thanks, but I can not use Macros.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it, without VBA, if you dont mind to use one auxiliary column

In the example(see picture) C1 contains the name, column D is the aux column and the ComboBox is in E1.

Write this array formula in D1 (dont forget to enter it with Ctrl Shift Enter)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$10;SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$10=$C$1;ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW($A$2)+1;"");ROWS($A$1:A1)));"")
```

Copy this formula down till D10 (or when, at least, you got the first space)

Now in E1 enter Data Validation, List and in source enter the formula:

```
=OFFSET(D1;0;0;MATCH("";D:D;0)-1;1)
```

Depending on your regional settings you may need to replace ";" by ","

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it didnt work. I am getting #N/A instead of List. Any advise?

Comment: It works, I tried it :) Copy the formula in D1 down, till, at least, you got the first empty space, dont forget to Ctrl Shift Enter. See my Edit, formula is to be in D1 not C1. The formula for Data validation will try to find the first space in order to know when the range ends.

Comment: Now it worked. Question: Is there a way to avoid Column D and put the equation of Column D into the OFFSET function?